# MSBUILD error MSB3073 Exited with code 100

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, post-build

I am using msbuild to build setup and in there when following line of code hit there will be an error

```
    <!-- Add mappings to the workspace -->
<Exec Command="$(TfCommand) workfold /map /workspace:$(WorkSpaceName) /server:$(ServerName) $(SourceControlMainDirectory-Customizations) $(SolutionRoot-Customizations)" WorkingDirectory="$(SolutionRoot-Customizations)" ContinueOnError="false" />
```

Error is

```
"D:\Mubasher Net Plus - Asia\Branches\FeaturesDevelopment_R5\Build\Scripts\IndonesiaDT5-XOPO\Build-IndonesiaDT.proj" (default target) (1) ->
```

(Get-Latest target) ->
D:\Mubasher Net Plus - Asia\Branches\FeaturesDevelopment_R5\Build\Scripts\Get-Latest-IndonesiaDT.proj(52,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe
" workfold /map /workspace:FeaturesDevelopment_R5 /server:http://192.0.0.0:8080/tfs/defaultcollection $/Mubasher Net Plus - Asia\Branches\FeaturesDevelopment_R5\Customizations" D:\MS_BUILD\MTECH\Branches\Fe
aturesDevelopment_R5\Customizations" exited with code 100. [D:\Mubasher Net Plus - Asia\Branches\FeaturesDevelopment_R5\Build\Scripts\IndonesiaDT5-XOPO\Build-IndonesiaDT.proj]

```
 <SolutionRoot-Customizations>D:\MS_BUILD\MTECH\Branches\FeaturesDevelopment_R5\Customizations</SolutionRoot-Customizations>
<SourceControlMainDirectory-Customizations>$/Mubasher Net Plus - Asia\Branches\FeaturesDevelopment_R5\Customizations"</SourceControlMainDirectory-Customizations>
<ServerName>http://192.0.0.0:8080/tfs/defaultcollection</ServerName>
<TfCommand>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe"</TfCommand>
<WorkspaceName>FeaturesDevelopment_R5</WorkspaceName>
```

How to overcome this?

Comment: [Exit with code 100](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ms194959(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) means nothing succeeded. You can see [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/workfold-command?view=azure-devops) about the TF Command

Answer (score 0):

The `tf` command line is not correct. When using the `/map` switch the server folder and local folder should be provided after the switch and before any other options.

Running the command

```
tf vc help workfold
```

Shows the following syntax

```
tf vc workfold /map serverfolder localfolder
               [/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl]
               [/workspace:workspacename]
               [/login:username,[password]]
```

Try the following instead. Note in addition to rearranging the options and arguments, I have also added quotes around the file paths.

```
<Exec Command="$(TfCommand) workfold /map &quot;$(SourceControlMainDirectory-Customizations)&quot; &quot;$(SolutionRoot-Customizations)&quot; /workspace:$(WorkSpaceName) /server:$(ServerName)"
  WorkingDirectory="$(SolutionRoot-Customizations)"
  ContinueOnError="false" />
```